# Search a key in a Json (nested array) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, wunderground

I use WU api to get some hourly weather data. The API returns a Json with multiple hourly values and I want to query the one that I need:

Json:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "hourly": 1
  }
    }
        ,
    "hourly_forecast": [
        {
        "FCTTIME": {
        "hour": "13","hour_padded": "13","min": "00","min_unpadded": "0","sec": "0","year": "2015","mon": "12","mon_padded": "12","mon_abbrev": "Dec","mday": "30","mday_padded": "30","yday": "363","isdst": "0","epoch": "1451509200","pretty": "1:00 PM PST on December 30, 2015","civil": "1:00 PM","month_name": "December","month_name_abbrev": "Dec","weekday_name": "Wednesday","weekday_name_night": "Wednesday Night","weekday_name_abbrev": "Wed","weekday_name_unlang": "Wednesday","weekday_name_night_unlang": "Wednesday Night","ampm": "PM","tz": "","age": "","UTCDATE": ""
        },
        "temp": {"english": "60", "metric": "16"},
        "dewpoint": {"english": "34", "metric": "1"},
        "condition": "Clear",
        "icon": "clear"
        }
        ,
        {
        "FCTTIME": {
        ...
        }
        ,
        "FCTTIME": {
        ...
        },
        ... more FCTTIME
   ]
}
```

This is my code to get `hourly_forecast` as array:

```
$jsonRequest    = file_get_contents("weather.json");
$data           = json_decode($jsonRequest, true);

$array   = @$data['hourly_forecast'];
```

I need to get the `temp` and `condition` for `"hour": "13"`. So the PHP would print something like: `The weather is $condition with $temp degree.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to loop over the set of hourly forecasts, and when you find the one that matches the hour you are looking for, get the values you want from that forecast and then break out of the loop.

```
foreach ($data['hourly_forecast'] as $forecast) {
    if ($forecast['FCTTIME']['hour'] == 13) {
        $condition = $forecast['condition'];
        $temp = $forecast['temp'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, I had to change to `$temp = $forecast['temp']['english'];`

Answer (score 2):

First dont convert an object to an array, there is no need to.

So change `$data = json_decode($jsonRequest, true);`

To `$data = json_decode($jsonRequest);`

Then loop over the `$data->hourly_forecast` array looking for the specific time you need like this

```
foreach( $data->hourly_forecast as $forecast ) {
    if ( $forecast->FCTTIME->hour == 13 ) {
        echo 'The time  ' . $forecast->FCTTIME->hour.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'The temp F' . $forecast->temp->english.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'The temp C' . $forecast->temp->metric.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'The condition ' . $forecast->condition.PHP_EOL;

        // if this is all you need, stop looping
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this loop doesn't echo anything.

Comment: Did you change the `$data = json_decode($jsonRequest);`

Comment: I actually tested it and it runs for me using PHP CLI, maybe you should change the `PHP_EOL` to `'<br>'` if you are using a browser

Comment: I actually changed it before I commented, but well it works now. Thanks

Comment: Is there any advantage of your code over the accepted answer?

Comment: Not really, other than using the data as provided and not converting it all to an array. I personnally prefer object references over array references.